# How to show content of my plugins in wordpress's page

Tags: php, wordpress

First of all, i have created a simple plugin name "test" which contains this code 
 `function fetch_content()
{
    echo "Hello world";
}` 

Then i have added a new page named "Display" and in its Page attribute section, the Template is set to Default.
So my question is -  How to display the output "Hello world" in the page which I have added in Wordpress ? 
Thank you..

Comment: Hi 

Call the function in your code.

Comment: yes.. I did that too , but the content "Hello World" is being displayed in all wordpress pages @AndrewOsenga

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to call the function that you create in plugin. Something like it :

```
function fetch_content()
{
    echo "Hello world";
} 
fetch_content();
```

It will show the output as you expected.

**NOTE : Remember to active the plugin after you install it.**

Comment: Using this code, the "Hello world" is being displayed in all the pages @Tristup

Comment: Plugin will react same with all the pages. If you need to add it to specific page. I suggest you to create a shortcode in your plugin and call it in page content. And will be shown where it calls.

Comment: add_shortcode("show_hello_world","fetch_content"); write this code just after the function end. And paste this code to page content [show_hello_world]. Hope this will work for you

Comment: Yes, I have tried it and it works Thank you. @Tristup 
but i want something else like that in Buddypress. . 
In buddypress we have to create a page "Activity" then we have to attach this page in Buddypress settings(Activity streams).. And then we see the output in Activity page that all the Site-wide activities are shown there..

Comment: Do you know how the buddypress does that...that is not at all a easy task... you need to spent more time on it..

Answer (score 0):

This might help--

You can call the function in page.php (inside your themes folder) like this-

```
if(is_page("page-slug"))
{
   fetch_content();
}
```

If the page slug of the "Display" page that you have created is "display",then it will be like this--

```
 if(is_page("display"))
{
   fetch_content();
}
```